# Ошибка в очистке памяти

Tags: c++, указатели, память, односвязный-список

Появляется ошибка при очистке head в `delStack()`, и я не понимаю в чем проблема.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    string name;
    int amount;
}Data;

struct Node {
    Data info;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head;

Node* addStack(Data add) {
    Node* p;
    p = new Node[sizeof(Node)];
    if (p) {
        p->info = add;
        p->next = head;
        head = p;

    }
    return p;
}

void printStack() {
    struct Node* p;
    cout << "======================\n";
    p = head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p->info.name << "\t" << p->info.amount << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void delStack() {
    Node* p;
    p = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = p;
}

int main() {
    
    Data s;
    head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> s.name;
        cin >> s.amount;
        if (!addStack(s)) {
            cout << "Error of adding element in stack" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    printStack();
    delStack();

}
```

Comment: возможно, в ошибке написано, почему она возникает. Обычно ошибки для того и пишутся, чтобы их читали.

Comment: появляется ошибка виндовс

Comment: `p = new Node[sizeof(Node)];` — т.е. вы создаете массив из `Node` в количестве элементов, равном размеру `Node` в байтах? :)

Comment: я учусь на курсу по c++, но изучаем мы C. в примере на C было написано так, но с malloc, но спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас такая ядреная смесь французского (С++) с нижегородским (С), что проще исправить код и попросить вас разобраться, почему он исправлен именно так...

Одно смешение `new` и `free`, а равно неверное применение `new` чего стоит.

Кстати, код получился далеко не лучший, но тут я был ограничен вашей, так сказать, парадигмой.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    string name;
    int amount;
};

struct Node
{
    Data info;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head;

Node* addStack(const Data& add)
{
    Node* p = new Node;
    p->info = add;
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
    return p;
}

void printStack()
{
    Node* p = head;
    cout << "======================\n";
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        cout << p->info.name << "\t" << p->info.amount << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void delStack(Node* p = head)
{
    if (p == nullptr) return;
    delStack(p->next);
    delete p;
}

int main() {
    
    Data s;
    head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> s.name;
        cin >> s.amount;
        if (!addStack(s)) {
            cout << "Error of adding element in stack" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    printStack();
    delStack();

}
```

Comment: ладно, всё равно спасибо

Comment: Ну посмотрите все отличия. Не расписывать же каждый чих — типа, `typedef struct ...` — сугубо C'шная конструкция... Что `new` при нехватке памяти генерирует исключение, а не возвращает NULL. etc etc etc Вы, похоже, изучали С, а теперь переезжаете на С++?

Comment: Я сейчас на курсе по C++, но изучаем мы C(скоро будет С++), поэтому пробую сразу на C++. В примере этого кода всё было написано на C, а я всё что знал написал на C++

Comment: Тогда лучше было писать на С. Это заблуждение, что С просто подмножество С++, или что С++ просто улучшенный С. Это действительно разные языки, разные подходы, и лучше их не смешивать - ничего хорошего из этого, как правило, не получается...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...

Comment: у меня мало репутации и не видно, но я уже нажал